# Beyond Compare 4 - How to use own compare engine for new file type

Tags: beyondcompare

I want to write a small program to compare two sql lite dbs.

i wrote just a Hello World progamm and added the .exe under tools -> file formats -> command line. (just `Console.Out.WriteLine("Hello World");`)

[image]

Beyond Compare throws an error, every time and try to compare twei ndbs.

[image]

Any suggetions?
I tried the full path and copied into bc.exe folder a tried only the filename.

Comment: I suggest you submit a bug report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond Compare expects an output file. If it isn't there Beyond Compare crashes.

I got it working, if someone want to check it out, here is the link to GitHub
[Beyond-Compare-SQLite-Plugin](https://github.com/dhcgn/BeyondCompareSQLitePlugin)

[image: Screenshot of SQLite-Plugin for Beyond Compare]